# How can I get the XP needed for the next level

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot that allows message levels and xp to be tracked;

```
if (message.guild.id == "509850431640305664") {
const key = `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`;

villa.points.ensure(`${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`, {
user: message.author.id,
guild: message.guild.id,
points: 0,
level: 0
});

villa.points.inc(key, "points");

const curLevel = Math.floor(.25 * Math.sqrt(villa.points.get(key, "points")));
if (villa.points.get(key, "level") < curLevel) {
    message.author.send({embed: {color: '0x188088',description: `\\ **Level-up** | You advanced to level **${curLevel}**!`,footer: {text: `${villa.footerText}`, icon_url: `${villa.footerImage}`}}});
    villa.points.set(key, curLevel, "level");
}

if (message.author.id == "153638972013281282") {
    console.log(Math.floor(.25 * Math.sqrt(villa.points.get(key, "points"))));
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(villa.points.get(key, "level")) / .25));
}
}
```

however I am not sure how to get the XP NEEDED to level up; I calculate level with the line below;

```
const curLevel = Math.floor(.25 * Math.sqrt(villa.points.get(key, "points")));
```

Is there a way I could do that expression in reverse to get XP till next level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each levels' XP required can be calculated by:

> XP = (Level * 4)^2

When we know our current XP, we just need to subtract that from the required amount to find the remainder:

```
var curPoints = villa.points.get(key, "points");         //Our current XP
var curLevel = Math.floor(.25 * Math.sqrt(curPoints));

var pointsNextLevel = Math.pow((curLevel + 1) * 4, 2);   //Required XP
var pointsRequired = pointsNextLevel - curPoints;        //Result
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have another question. Lets say I want to get the progress as a Percent

I'd normally do 
`let progress = (curPoints / pointsNextLevel) * 100;`

However since the curPoints does not reset everytime a user levels up they can go from 99% to 65% towards next level.

How can I get the progress as a percent to the next level while also accounting for this?

Comment: Level 2 = 64 points. Level 3 = 144 points. Say you had 110 points, you'd want the percentage to be 57% (46/80) rather than 76% (110/144)? If this is the case, you'd need to find the points for the current level (`Math.pow(curLevel * 4, 2)`) & subtract them from both `curPoints` & `pointsNextLevel` in your `progress` calculation.